# What's up with my Laravel route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This works fine:

```
Route::get('blade-second', function()
{
  $slug = 'star-wars';
  $movies = array(
    'star-wars' => array('name' => 'Star Wars', 'year'
     => '1977', 'genre' => 'Sci-Fi'),
    ...
  );
  return View::make('blade.second')->with('movie', $movies[$slug]);
});
```

but replace it with this:

```
Route::get('blade-second/(:any)', function($slug)
{
  $movies = array( ... );

  return View::make('blade.second')->with('movie', $movies[$slug]);
});
```

and it results in a `200 NotFoundHttpException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use brackets, and no colon

```
'blade-second/{any}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is Laravel 4, that syntax is no longer valid and you should use the style listed in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/routing.

---

Comment: Aha! So perhaps my Cookbook example is out of date.  Though that's a bit strange, it's meant to be for Laravel 4.0 as far as I can tell.  I've installed Laravel 4.1, would that make a difference?